# I am really confused, GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1 is the latest version of Admob SDK?

Tags: sdk, admob

i am really confused with this question!
After searching everywhere and without getting a good answer, i come here to ask you.
In my Admob Account appears a Warning message that says: "Remember that, as of August 1, 2014, all application upgrades and new applications that are uploaded to Google Play Store must comply with the provision on advertising ID policy Developer Program. Upgrade your SDK to the version of Google Play SDK mobile ads to comply with this provision and take advantage of new features, including automatic updates and bug fixes." (i used google translator, cause it was in spanish)
My confussion is, THE LATEST VERSION of Admob IS this: "GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1"
Or there is a new one, that i MUST update it? (yeah, i know, August 1 was 2 weeks ago)...
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of Admob isn't "GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1". That's deprecated. The latest version is available via the google play services library.

You don't have to make changes to your existing apps on the play store.

"However, from 1st August, 2014, for updates or new apps using ads to be accepted on the play store, they must use an advertising ID. In admob, this is only available via the google play services library and not the deprecated GoogleAdmobADSSdk-6.X.X.jar so you within your apps make sure you use admob via the google play service library.

[According to](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/2IgChJZ0w8I) Eric (Google Admob developer engineer):

"The SDK upgrade deadline on August 1st per the Google Play Ad Policy just means you can't update apps to the Google Play store that include the old AdMob SDK."

Follow the official guide on migrating to the new admob [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration). Reference the google play services library within your project and make the following changes:

Change the lines:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxx"); // Put in your secret key here
      adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

to:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(activity);
adView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxx");
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder()
.build());
```

And in your manifest file:

Change:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"/>
```

to:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Don't forget the permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```